# With inotifywait, exclude files that have certain extensions

Tags: shell-script, filenames, inotify

I am watching incoming encrypted files which have two extensions, e.g., `testfile<date>.dat.pgp`.

The problem is: once the file is decrypted,
it creates a new file (`testfile<date>.dat`) in the monitor directory,
which triggers another unwanted run of the watch process.

How do I exclude `testfile<date>.dat` but include `testfile<date>.dat.pgp` ?

This is my code:

```
inotifywait -m -e create --format '%w%f'  "${MONITORDIR}"  |  while read  NEWFILE
do

    #decrypts testfile.dat.pgp
    # new file "testfile<date>.dat" is created in the $MONITOR_DIR which triggers
    # the inotifywait process to run again.

done
```

Answer (score 1):

Piping your call to `grep`

```
inotifywait -m -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" |\
grep '.dat.pgp$' --line-buffered | while read  NEWFILE 
   do

   #decrypts testfile.dat.pgp
   # new file "testfile.dat" is created in the $MONITOR_DIR which triggers
   # the inotifywait process to run again.

   done
```

will make `inotifywait` to watch only files with the extension `.dat.pgp`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I modified your suggestion a bit to remove

Comment: I removed "/*.dat.pgp" and this worked:  inotifywait -m  -e create --format '%w%f'  "${MONITORDIR}" |\
grep '.dat.pgp$' --line-buffered |  while read  NEWFILE

Comment: @ChrisHall Updated answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably skip the files inside the while read loop also.

```
    inotifywait -m -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" |\
    while read  -r NEWFILE; do 
       if [[ $NEWFILE == *.dat.pgp ]]; then
        #decrypts testfile.dat.pgp
        # new file "testfile.dat" is created in the $MONITOR_DIR which triggers
        # the inotifywait process to run again.
       fi
    done
```

I have not tested that code but the test should only process the files that ends with `*.dat.gpg`